# JavaMail issue to send automatially

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am currently trying to get AlarmReceiver to send an email when triggered by DatePicker/TimePicker. Now, this is already working successfully for sending a push notification to the mobile device. And i also know the SendMail method works in a different project.

This should be working, but i can't see any problems with the code for triggering the SendMail method once the AlarmReceiver class is called?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

**Alarm.java**

```
package com.example.pc.achieve;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Alarm extends Activity{

DatePicker pickerDate;
TimePicker pickerTime;
Button buttonSetAlarm;
TextView info;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

final static int RQS_1 = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    pickerDate = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.pickerdate);
    pickerTime = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.pickertime);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    pickerDate.init(
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
            null);

    pickerTime.setCurrentHour(now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    pickerTime.setCurrentMinute(now.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    buttonSetAlarm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setalarm);
    buttonSetAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(pickerDate.getYear(),
                    pickerDate.getMonth(),
                    pickerDate.getDayOfMonth(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentHour(),
                    pickerTime.getCurrentMinute(),
                    00);

            if(cal.compareTo(current) <= 0){
                //The set Date/Time already passed
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Date/Time Has Already Passed!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {
                setAlarm(cal);
            }

        }});

}


private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _id, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your alarm for this deadline has now been set for "  + targetCal.getTime())
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast receiver execution might be quick.

Better you should kick start a intent service for sending an email.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So this execution may be too quick? I would like the email to be automatic when the alarm is triggered, is it not possible to complete it this way? OnClick works for this method in a separate project  and the email is sent instantly.

Comment: I meant to say instead of using AsyncTask, you can use Intent Service which will be running​ in the background process, but AsyncTask may not.

Comment: Ahh i see, i am still new to java and unsure how to change this method to use intent service instead of AsyncTask? Thank you for the help!